# Performing variable substitution in a string

Tags: bash

I have a string that contains a use of some variable, and I'd like to substitute that variable's value into the string.  Right now the best I have is

```
#!/bin/bash

foo='$name; echo bar'
name="The    name"
expanded="$(eval echo "$foo")"
echo "$expanded"
```

Which has some obvious defects: it prints

```
The name
bar
```

while I'd like it to print

```
The    name; echo bar
```

Comment: sounds like a xy problem to me. what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: I second huStmphHrrr's sentiment

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr You're right of course, but I am more curious about this than a solution to my actual problem which I have already solved a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but this works and you do not have (nor probably want) to use `eval`:

```
 name="The    name"
 foo="$name; echo bar"
 echo "$foo
```

prints

```
The    name; echo bar
```

Comment: In my case `foo` is a command line parameter, so I have no chance to define it after `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `eval` you can do bash's regex matching with bash's string replacement:

```
foo='$name; echo bar'
name="The    name"
[[ "$foo" =~ \$([[:alnum:]]+) ]] && s="${!BASH_REMATCH[1]}" &&
  expanded="${foo/\$${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/$s}"

echo "$expanded"
The    name; echo bar
```

Comment: I'd like to do it for all variables that are currently defined, and support all of bash's syntax like `${name:-default}` etc

Comment: ok check my updated answer for a generic solution. If there are multiple variable to be replaced then above snippet can also be run using a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="The    '     \" name"
foo="$name; echo bar"
expanded=$(eval 'echo "$foo"')
echo "$expanded"
```

Output:

```
The    '     " name; echo bar
```

Comment: It should be `The    name; echo bar` though (4 spaces).  EDIT: spaces got collapsed by the comment system, they go between `The` and `name`.

Comment: Thanks!  Doesn't work if `name` contains `'` though.

Comment: hmm, ok, another update.. name can contain both ' and " , and preserve all the spaces..